# How to deploy Symfony app in AWS Code Deploy using Github?

Tags: php, shell, symfony, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am using AWS Code Deploy to deploy a Symfony project to an autoscaling group consisting of multiple EC2 instances. Currently I deploy revisions for my application using the S3 file upload option, however I would prefer  being able to deploy directly from Github.

The problem I have is what to do about the parameters.yml file? It contains a variety of sensitive information required for the application to run. I therefore don't want to push a production configuration of the parameters.yml into remote repo, for a number of reasons.

What would you recommend doing?

I was wondering if I can write a shell script which is executed AfterInstall and copies across the prod parameters.yml from a s3 bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current best practice in symfony is to use environment variables, see [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/configuration/external_parameters.html) for more information. And I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523542/environment-variables-using-aws-codedeploy) with hints for setting the variables.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about doing this actually. I think I maybe able to use the parameter store under EC2 system manager.